# What can I use to limit the range of a Cantor pairing function to 255?

Tags: mathematics

I have 2 data input sets [0-20] and [0-7] and I need a pairing function like CANTOR to restrict the mapped value to [0 - 255]. Would it be feasible to use MOD(256) to restrict the result?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The CANTOR pairing function starts yielding integers north of 255 when it reaches [15,7] - i would like to restrict the result to stay within [0,255]  and MOD is what comes to mind, although the requirement would be that MOD is reversible, which i dont think it is ...